# What is the meaning of these Kubernetes annotations?

Tags: kubernetes

in the output of $ kubectl describe node ip-10-0-1-21

I receive the following annotations:

```
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
```

can you please tell me the meaning of them and if there is a universal guide for all of these annotations - I could not find them by googling.

is there any logic how these annotations are created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl` is a tuning parameter for how long the Kubelet can cache objects, only rarely used for extreme high-density or high-scale clusters. `controller-managed-attach-detach` is a feature flag from long ago, Kubernetes 1.3. It was originally used to enable or disable the attach-detach-controller for specific nodes. From the code it looks like it probably still works though that controller has been the default mode for years so we should probably remove it some day.

Comment: Many thanks, is there any reference to support your answers? Only some annotations are available here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/

Comment: Check the code, both are well documented in the Go doc comments.

Comment: @yurasov you can find the ttl annotation in the Kubernetes source code at: `/pkg/apis/core/annotation_key_constants.go`, the `controller-managed-attach-detach` can be found in the `CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.3.md`.